# Find max number from row then divide and subtract previous number

Tags: r

For example:

```
v1 <- c(10, 11, 20, 30, 40, 50, 30, 25, 20, 10)
```

In `v1` `50` is a max number, I need the below result

```
result <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, (50/40)-1, (30/50)-1, (25/30)-1, (20/25)-1, (10/20)-1)
```

The final array will look like this

```
c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, -0.4, -0.16, -0.2, -0.5)
```

Comment: Why are the first values 0?

Comment: here we need to find erosion, the numbers are in million dollars, when numbers start dropping after pick then we need to find erosion, i.e negative percentage gap for each next year, so that's why we consider all the values will zero before max value (pick value)

Comment: Will the numbers always increase then decrease or is it possible to have a random vector?

Comment: After max (peak) next numbers will lesser than max

Comment: One change in that, can we also able to convert max number to Zero

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in the following, somewhat clunky, way using a combination of base R's `which.max()` and `dplyr`'s `lag()` function and some indexing:

```
c(rep(0,which.max(v1) - 1), v1[which.max(v1):length(v1)] / (dplyr::lag(v1[(which.max(v1)-1):length(v1)]))[-1]-1)
```

Output:

```
#[1]  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.2500000 -0.4000000 -0.1666667 -0.2000000
#[10] -0.5000000
```

To break this down to more palatable code:

```
numerator <- v1[which.max(v1):length(v1)]
denominator <- lag(v1[(which.max(v1) - 1):length(v1)])[-1]
leading_zeros <- rep(0, which.max(v1) - 1)

c(leading_zeros, numerator/denominator - 1)

#[1]  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.2500000 -0.4000000 -0.1666667 -0.2000000
#[10] -0.5000000
```

Comment: Are you using `lag` from stats or from `dplyr`? if the later, then this is not purely base R

Comment: yes, thank you for pointing this omission out - see edit

Comment: You have 11 output. It should be 10

Comment: One change in that, can we also able to convert max number to Zero

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach that leverages `data.table::shift()`

```
f <- function(v) {
  mx = which.max(v); 
  c(rep(0,mx-1), (v/shift(v)-1)[mx:length(v)])
}
```

Usage:

```
f(v1)
```

Output:

```
 [1]  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.2500000 -0.4000000 -0.1666667 -0.2000000 -0.5000000
```

Comment: One change in that, can we also able to convert max number to Zero

Comment: i dont know what you mean. find the max of the result, and convert that to zero? find the max of the original vector and convert that to zero before doing the calculation? please explain.

Answer (score 2):

in Base R we will do:

```
idx <- which.max(v1)
index <- seq_along(v1) >= idx - 1
c(numeric(idx - 1), tail(v1[index],-1)/head(v1[index], -1) - 1)

[1]  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.2500000 -0.4000000
 [8] -0.1666667 -0.2000000 -0.5000000
```

Comment: One change in that, can we also able to convert max number to Zero

Answer (score 2):

We may also do

```
library(dplyr)
replace((v1/lag(v1))-1, seq_along(v1) < which.max(v1), 0)
```

-output

```
[1]  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.2500000 -0.4000000 -0.1666667 -0.2000000 -0.5000000
```

Comment: One change in that, can we also able to convert the max number to Zero?

Comment: @MaheshKulkarni change the `<` or `<=`